# How can I install a Y wire for a Nest thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

Installed a new Nest thermostat yesterday. My setup is a 4 wire system.
Green, Blue, White, and red. I have central air and gas heat. They had the Blue wire "C" into the Y for the AC. Since the Nest needs constant power, I had to use the "C" blue wire for constant power for the Nest.  Now I have no wire for the central air. How difficult is it to install a "y" yellow wire so my AC will work?

Comment: Nest has good customer support. Have you tried that? You may just need to install a jumper.

Comment: Big thing to remember is colors are based on convention and whoever installed your A/C is not required to use the "correct" colors.  If your old thermostat had a blue wire going to the A/C terminal, it's very unlikely that is the "C" wire.  Probably more like "oh, blue is a cold color, I'll use that for A/C"...  In other words, you're looking for a solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: Is pulling a new thermostat cable an option?